# Make a jquery ajax POST inside a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a bunch of data inside a loop I'd like to POST to the server via jQuery.

My code is similar to the following:

```
var patients = [] // contains an array of patient objects I want to POST to server

var post = function(theUrl, theData, callback){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: theUrl,
        data: theData,
        success: callback,
        contentType: "application/json"
    });
}

var createdPatient = function(patient){
    //patient was created
}

$('#saveAll').click(function(event) {
    for (var i = 0;i < patients.length;i++) {
        var json = JSON.stringify(patients[i]);
        post("/openmrs/ws/rest/v1/patient", json, createdPatient);
    }
});
```

When I run the code only the last patient has been saved to the server. How may I correct this erroneous outcome?

Comment: Use the debugger to figure out what your code is doing.

Comment: Why aren't using async?

Comment: As of jQuery 1.8, the use of async: false with jqXHR ($.Deferred) is deprecated;

Comment: @orbit I got that from http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Hit F12 to open your developer tools, look for a tab that says "Network" on it.  Once you find that perform the action that causes the requests to happen.  Verify in the network console that the # of requests and their request data is accurate.  EDIT: Yeah, avoid async: false.

Comment: Pro Tip: Select the XHR filter in the Network Tab so you can see only ajax requests

Comment: how does your patient object look like?

Comment: I think it's an issue with the call been asynchronous. When I used async: false. It saves all patients in the array fine but the issue now is the fact that async: false is deprecated.

Comment: How many patient objects do you have? If it's something like 4 or 5 then I believe the code should work. But anything more than 6 it wont work. Your subsequent calls are queued. So you have to wait for the calls to complete and then trigger the ajax call again

Comment: 4 or 5 depends on how many live connections you have at that time in your application. If you have 4 videos open in your application then, you will have only two connections to use

Answer (score 0):

Taking advantage of the promise returned by `jQuery.ajax()`, you can write something more like this (see comments for detail) :

```
var patients = [...] // contains an array of patient objects to be POSTed to the server

$('#saveAll').click(function(event) {
    // first, map the `patients` array to an array of jqXHR promises as returned by $.ajax().
    var promises = patients.map(function(patient) {
        return $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/openmrs/ws/rest/v1/patient',
            data: patient, // jQuery.jax will handle js plain objects here. You may need to stringify here if patient is not a plain object.
            contentType: "application/json"
        }).then(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            return textStatus; // report successes in the form of the "textStatus" message (or anything you like).
        }, function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            return $.when(textStatus || errorThrown); // report error on the success path, otherwise `$.when()` will bail out at the first error.
        });
    });
    // Now aggregate the `promises` array with `$.when()`
    $.when.apply(null, promises).then(function(results) {
        console.log(results);
    }, function(error) {
        // due to error handling above, you should never get here.
        console.log(error);
    });
});
```

For more detail, see [jQuery.ajax()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and [jQuery.when()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/)